# What is the origin of the metrization problem for compact convex sets?

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, set-theory, gn.general-topology

The following is an ``old question in analysis:''
Is it true that every *perfectly normal* compact convex subset of a locally convex topological vector space is metrizable?
Here *perfectly normal* means Hausdorff plus all closed subsets are a countable intersection of open sets.

Who first asked this question?  The oldest reference I can locate is a 1972 paper by B. MacGibbon in the Journal of Functional Analysis but it is clear from what is written there that she is reporting progress on a known problem.

Of course I am also interested in an answer to this question, but I'm really asking about reference information.  I should note that Lopez-Abad and Todorcevic have recently demonstrated that it is consistent with ZFC that there is a counterexample to this problem.  The question is whether a positive answer is consistent.

Comment: Just for the education of those less knowledgeable, could you provide a definition (or pointer) for a _normal_ (compact convex) set?

Comment: @Joseph:"normal" as in separation property (aka T_4).  Since this is about compact spaces, this is the same as Hausdorff (I edited normal->Hausdorff).